# How to get the text in textField In TVOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-tv, tvos13

I am creating a login screen in my TVOS application. when I click on textField, keyboard opens and when I click on any key it switched to the textfield but no text shown in textfield.

Comment: add your code related to textField

Comment: I drag and drop it from the object library , I think there is no need to code  if needed please help,  as I worked on iPhone application there was no code needed if we use storyboard object library

Comment: Hi... Did you find anything on this..? have you added any code to make use of textfield !